# Why are none of my Text Content Visible on the Screen in android jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have created three texts one below the other inside a Column along with Icon Button and a Normal Button. But, the Screen isn't showing any of the Texts, it does show the IconButton and the normal Button though. Where am I going wrong? Following is my composable code.

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ArrowBack
import androidx.compose.material3.AlertDialog
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.ButtonDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.IconButton
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import com.mayoclinic.ecg_frontend_android.constants.Destinations


@Composable
fun OnBoardingScreen4(navController: NavController) {

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start, // Align the text to the left
        modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp)
    ){
        // Back icon at the top-left corner
        IconButton(
            onClick = {
                navController.popBackStack()
            },
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp, top = 8.dp)
        ) {
            // You can use any icon you like for the back button
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                contentDescription = null, tint = Color(0xFF039be5))
        }
    }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(311.dp)
            .height(40.dp)
            .padding(top = 120.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
    ) {
        // Image at the top-left corner
        // Add bold text below the image
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Text(
            text = "Risks & considerations",

            // mc-serif/headline-large
            style = TextStyle(
                fontSize = 32.sp,
                lineHeight = 40.sp,
                fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                fontWeight = FontWeight(700),
                color = Color(0xFF000000),
            )
            , modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 28.dp)
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Text(
            text = "The data you share will not be reviewed immediately and will not be used to assess your individual health.",
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 28.dp)
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Text(
            text = "If you need medical assistance, please call or visit with your health care provider.",
            fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 28.dp)
        )


    }
    Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(20.dp)){
        // Spacer to push the button to the bottom
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

        // Button centered at the bottom
        Button(
            onClick = {
                navController.navigate(Destinations.OnBoardingScreen5)
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(339.dp)
                .padding(top = 12.dp, bottom = 20.dp, start =
                24.dp, end = 24.dp)
                .height(48.dp),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(percent = 50),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xFF039be5))
        ) {
            Text(text = "Next", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, style =
            TextStyle(Color.White))
            }
        }

    }
```

I want the all three Texts one below the other with the same padding from the start , the padding that I have written in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Height of the `Column` with `40.dp` is not big enough to fit every item and you already occupy that space with `Modifier.padding(top = 120.dp)` after width and height Modifiers. After setting 40.dp height you try to give empty space that is high as 120.dp but it's limited 40.dp which is height of the `Column`. Order of height and padding modifier matter.

Even if you change order of padding your items still won't fit because 40.dp is not enough to fit Spacer with 20.dp height and `Text`s.

You can remove height modifier which lets Column height to be measured as big as its content or set another size Modifier to fit items.

Border is to show bounds of your column, it's for demonstration purposes.

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(top = 120.dp)
        .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
        .width(311.dp),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
) {
   // Spacers and Texts
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Modifier.padding can act as margin or padding based on Modifiers before and after it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72023768/5457853